# How to stop an App from interrupting Music?

Tags: ios, itunes, audio, bluetooth

When I'm squirting ***iTunes*** music to my Bluetooth speaker from my iPhone, if I open up an app with video- including an app running just video ads- the app will preempt the music i was listening to, stopping it. This is driving me insaniac. Not a showstopper of a fault, but a serious nuisance.

Although my iPhone is currently running **IOS 13.2**, this issue has existed as long as I can remember.

I've reviewed these apps' access in IOS Settings, but there is nothing relevant I can toggle off: "***Siri & Search***", "***Notifications***", "***Background App Refresh***" and "***Mobile Data***" are configurable options for such an app. None of these will be the culprit.

Further, I've reviewed "***Privacy***" in Settings and cannot find these offending Apps with the type of access that would preempt the ***iTunes*** Music piped via Bluetooth to my speaker.

Has anybody found a way to tame such misbehaving apps whose audio perform hostile takeovers of audio output?!?!?!

Comment: Is the Bluetooth portion relevant?  I think the behavior you're describing (apps hijacking audio) is a matter of how the apps  have configured their [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession)

Comment: Firstly, for the sake of completeness, I felt it was worth describing how things were organized; trying to solve a problem with sparse or incomplete data it tough.  As for Bluetooth itself, if I knew how my speaker was being hijacked by apps, I wouldn't have posted the question.  But yes, in order to hose my music, the offending App must be able to have access to that speaker.

Comment: I meant that I don't believe this is limited to when you're playing via Bluetooth (a Bluetooth device is going to play whatever audio your device is playing/sending).  If you weren't using Bluetooth (e.g. headphones, internal speaker, etc), this behavior exists as well.  In other words, not a Bluetooth issue, but audio in general

The reference to AVAudioSession was that this is a matter of how the apps you're switching to are coded, not an OS level issue.  As in there are likely some apps that you can switch to that will play both their audio and background the iTunesaudio just fine.

Comment: However it's happening, allowing other apps which feature video ads to take control of the audio output is not good. Agreed, IOS can't distinguish what's a video ad and what's a legitimate video, so Apple developers need to offer users some modality for limiting access on a granular basis.  At this point I'd welcome any dirty hack somebody has to defeat these nuisance video ads...

Comment: The nature of the interruption should be irrelevant — I should be able to set a switch so that *nothing* interrupts what’s currently playing, maybe it can buzz the phone but don’t mess with the external outputs!